# Why can't I use 'this' when creating this javascript object literal?

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

The html:

```
<div id="slide">
    <div>This is one</div>
    <div>This is two</div>
    <div>This is three</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var slider = {
    div: document.getElementById("slide"),
    divs: this.div.getElementsByTagName("div")
};

alert(slider.divs.length);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CAzN8/

When I run this, Chrome said `this.div` is undefined. What's wrong here?

[UPDATE] I found that if I change the code to:

```
var tmp = document.getElementById("slide");
var slider = {
    div: tmp,
    divs: tmp.getElementsByTagName("div")
};
```

It works. But why can't the first case work?

Comment: That's a *literal object*, not a "JSON object". JSON is a text format for representing data, so this question has nothting at all to do with JSON.

Comment: @Guffa JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. Since this is JavaScript and the code uses JavaScript's (literal) Object Notation, I think you will find this is in fact JSON.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks, but this question could still use a better title.  Perhaps "Why can't I use 'this' when creating this javascript object?'

Comment: @Paul When I post the question, I didn't realize that it's `this` that cause the problem.

Comment: @wong2 That's fine.  I thought your question was interesting enough to need a title so that others later can read it if it applies to them.

Comment: really it's about "scoping rules for `this` inside JavaScript object literals"

Comment: True, but is a more novice-friendly title possible?

Comment: @Paul That's a good point. I think your suggest "Why can't I use 'this' when creating this javascript object?" is great, I will change to that.

Comment: @Paul, +1 which is precisely why I didn't change it myself, I'd suggest "this literal JS object" rather than "just this object" though

Comment: @tobyodavies JSON is a data interchange format, so if you see something that looks like JSON not used for that purpose it probably isn't. Yes, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, but it doesn't follow that all object literal notation within JavaScript is automatically JSON. For one thing JSON is just a subset of what you can do with object literals in JavaScript. For another, the specific example in the question is not valid JSON because the property names are not in quotes, even though that is perfectly valid in JavaScript.

Comment: JSON isn't just an interchange format, it's also used as a file format. it is, as it's name suggests, a notation - simply a way of writing something. Yes the example is not strict JSON but I don't think it is helpful to say (As Guffa did) that JavaScript's object notation has nothing to do with JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: @tobyodavies: No, Javascript is *not* JSON. Just because JSON is based on Javascript doesn't mean that it's correct to say that Javascript literal objects are JSON. The code in the question is not even valid JSON if you take it out of its context and try to use it as JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what `this` is , is dynamically determined by the method being called, not the lexical block the code resides in.

Simply using `this` inside the body of a JSON object does not mean it refers to the object being constructed. It almost certainly refers instead to the global window object.

If you want to be able to use `this` you'd want a constructor:

```
function Slider(id,tagName){
    this.div  = document.getElementById(id);
    this.divs = this.div.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
}

s = new Slider('slide','div')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't use this is because the JSON object hasn't actually been initialized yet. This is how I would do what you're trying to do:

```
var slider = {
    my_div: document.getElementById("slide");
};

slider.my_divs = slider.my_div.getElementsByTagName("div");
alert(slider.my_divs.length);
```

or

```
var my_div = document.getElementById("slide");

var slider = {
    my_div: my_div,
    my_divs: my_div.getElementsByTagName("div")
};

alert(slider.my_divs.length);
```

Comment: because `this` in that context is not the object you are constructing.

Comment: Oh yes! Could I refer to `slider`'s `my_div` when I construct `slider`? I mean that I don't want a `my_div` outside `slider`

Comment: see my answer for how to use a constructor to use `this` correctly, (note the use of the `new` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Because the object hasn't actually been instantiated yet. This will work though:

```
var slider = {
    div: document.getElementById("slide"),
    divs: document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")
};
```

or

```
var slider = {};
slider.div = document.getElementById("slide");
slider.divs = slider.div.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work cause, when creating the object literal (what's inside brackets), the object doesn't exist yet, so `this` is undefined.

It's like thinking you could be your own father, you don't exist the moment of your creation.

Comment: `this` should not be undefined, it should be the `window` object.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the reserved word, but its meaning. Maybe I should have said "undeclared"